# I am unable to type cast string to integer in csh

Tags: linux, scripting, csh

I want to fetch out '-0.5' from the file example.txt and add 1 to it.

Although I am able to fetch out '-0.5'. but I am unable to add 1 to it, maybe because -0.5 is considered as a
string and not a integer.

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/csh
set x = `grep Name example.txt | cut -d "|" | -f 5`
echo $x
set y = `expr $x + 1`
echo $y
```

**Obtained Result:**

```
-0.5    
expr: non-numeric argument
```

**Expected Result:**

```
-0.5
0.5
```

**How do I type cast -0.5 to integer**?

Comment: -0.5 is not an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csh doesn't have types, and everything is a string.

The problem is that `expr` only accepts integers: that is, whole numbers. The same applies to csh's built-in `@` syntax.

It's usually better to use `bc` or `dc` for this:

```
% echo 0.5 + 1 | bc
1.5

% echo 0.5 1 + p | dc
1.5
```

So in your example:

```
#!/bin/csh
set x = `grep Name example.txt | cut -d "|" | -f 5`
set y = `echo "$x + 1" | bc`
echo $y
```